# How would a sword go about leaving behind distortions in space?

Tags: technology, magic, physics, weapons

How would one go about making a sword leave a distortion in space after it's swung?

For example- A sword is swung akin to a baseball bat swing, from behind the shoulder to make an arc in front of the user. When activated, the sword leaves an arc that matches where the blade of the sword had been during that swing. The arc is broader in the center but thinner towards the edges that were farthest from the user- like the sword itself.

This arc functions as though the sword were still in the area even though the user might no longer be touching said arc or even in the same area.

- If you were to touch the arc- your hand would be cut like it was hit by the sword as it passed.
- If you were to strike the arc with an object- the arc would be destroyed if your own strike would've been enough to stop the sword swing that left it there.
- If you were to strike the arc with an object- the object would be cut or deflected aside if your strike wouldn't have been enough to stop the sword swing that left it there.
- If you were to step atop the arc correctly- it would form a vibrating surface that could be stood upon.
- If a bullet were to strike a thin edge of the arc- the bullet would split like it was cut. If a bullet were to strike the fat of the arc- the bullet would deform like it hit a wall.
- The arc will vanish after existing for only a few seconds.

This is in a universe where genetic manipulation allows people to perform supernatural feats such as reading minds and manipulating time- so strict adherence to our physical laws is not required.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: As you've aptly tagged, the answer is literally "magic" - specifically, whatever magic you want

Comment: You're question isn't off-topic but it is opinion based. Given your world contains magic and you haven't given us any constraints on this magic then the answer to your question is use magic.

Comment: @Faerindel - I was asking if there's a way within our own rules of physics if someone could leave behind a trail when they attacked. Failing that, I was wondering what 'magic' explanations people could come up with to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're not adhering to the laws of physics, any perturbation in the handwavium field will suffice.

What you are talking about is physically impossible. Any answer that "sounds plausible" will work. It often isn't worth it to bend over backwards trying shoehorn in an explanation if you're just wanting something to look cool. Skip it entirely, and just describe your awesome fight scene.

Comment: I did figure it was physically impossible but I thought it couldn't hurt to ask. I assume from context 'handwavium' means something akin to 'a wizard did it'?

Comment: Basically yes. To handwave means to gloss over the details as trivial. Handwavium is any element, subatomic particle, or field that allows an explanation to gloss over its physical impossibility.